WP - How do I undo "Restore this Revision" action
I accidentally clicked "Restore this Revision" button while checking the 4-year old version of main page of WordPress website. Before that, the latest version I had was from 2 months ago (current one at the moment). After pressing "Restore this Revision", I still have the latest (current) version from 2 months ago, so I can't restore it (grayed button).
How do I undo the "Restore this Revision" action so the page is back to the version, let's say, 1 hour before I pressed this button?
